# How to convert YYYYMM to datetime?

Tags: datetime, powerbi

In PowerBi I have a dateslicer that uses a Datetime column from one of my tables.

The problem is that some of my other sources simply has a YYYYMM format for their dates, so I cannot make any relations to the datetime column.

Here I have them lined up next to each other. On the left is the Datetime column. On the right is the custom made YYYYMM date.

[image: example]

The actual day should just be the first of the month, and the time doesn't really matter, so 12:00:00 AM should be fine.

Is there a way to do this?

I've looked through all the datetime methods in an attempt to find a method that allows this to happen. Doesn't look like there's an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can treat the `YearMonth` as a string and write:

```
Date = DATE ( LEFT ( Table1[YearMonth], 4 ), RIGHT ( Table1[YearMonth], 2 ), 1 )
```

Comment: Brilliant! That is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a date column in your data table based on the yearMonth column then you can create it like this:

```
Date = 
DATE(
    ([YearMonth]-MOD([YearMonth];100))/100; 
    MOD([YearMonth];100);
     1
    )
```

Result:

[image]